# Java boolean to stop painting a component (to allow for user input via dialog) does not actually stop the paint taking place

Tags: java

As the title suggests, i am making a snake game and when the user is deemed to be dead (this is a simple boolean) the user is greeted with a YES/NO dialog. When this dialog is shown i want the game to stop/pause painting in order to allow the user to select their choice.

The problem i am having is, when the dialog is drawn repaint is being called over and over, so the dialog is getting drawn again and again, which ultimately crashes the application and makes the user unable to select their choice. I tried to control this with a boolean but it did not resolve the problem.

There is a lot of code, so i will try to post only the relevant parts.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        snake = Snake.snake;
        if (snake.over){
            snake.paint = false;
            System.out.println("Paint: " + snake.paint);
            int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would you like to Submit your high score?","Game Over!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                System.out.println("Yes option");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Non-yes option!");

            }

        }

    }
```

Now as you can see, when `snake.over == true` then `snake.paint == false` this should stop repaint being called, but it does not (see below).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(paint){
            render.repaint();
        }
}
```

This is the only place in my code where `repaint()` is called, so this boolean should in fact stop this from happening (but it does not).

There is a `Timer` which is operating on a 20ms delay, this is what calls the above `actionPerformed` method.

The print statment contained in the `paintComponent` method prints the following at runtime:

```
Paint: false
Paint: false
Paint: false
Paint: false
Paint: false
Paint: false
Paint: false
Paint: false
and so forth...
```

Does anybody know a way i can achieve what i want?

Ultimately i want this:

```
1) The user gets game over (dies).
2) The game then prompts the user if they want to upload their score using the above dialog (this means the game no longer needs to be repainted
3) The correct action then takes place based on the users decision from (2).
```

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: The paintComponent method should be strictly for painting and not for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: in your main game loop you should have a check for snake.over, if its set to true then you would have the prompt come up. but that is after the paint method

Comment: Ye i made the mistake of putting the dialog in the paint method, i was under the impression that dialog's were painted for some strange reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to not draw the Dialog's in the paint method but to implement this in my game loop:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            render.repaint();
            if(over){
                int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would you like to Submit your high score?","Game Over!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    System.out.println("Yes option");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Non-yes option!");

                }
            }
}
```